# "not equal to" operator not working in if-else statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, bit-manipulation

I have to check whether K-th bit of a number is set or not.

Example what I mean:

Input: N = 4, K = 0

Output: false

Explanation: Binary representation of 4 is `b'100`, in which the 0th bit from LSB is not set and therefore it returns false.

This code does not work with the not equal to the statement:

```c
bool checkKthBit(int n, int k)
{
    if( n & (1 << k) != 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

However, after removing the not equal operator the code works perfectly fine:

```c
bool checkKthBit(int n, int k)
{
    if (n & (1 << k))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

How is this happening?

Comment: What language is this?  Please add the relevant tag.

Comment: For C or C++, check compiler warnings: `!=` has higher precedence than `&`, so you'd want to write `if((n&(1<<k))!=0)`.

Comment: Consider going a step further `bool checkKthBit(int n, int k) { return n & (1 << k); }`.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the equation into brackets it does what you want:

https://godbolt.org/z/enTcjhrzT

```c
bool checkA(int n, int k) {
    if(n&(1<<k)!=0) return true; else return false;
}

bool checkB(int n, int k) {
    if((n&(1<<k))!=0) return true; else return false;
}

bool checkC(int n, int k) {
    if((n&(1<<k))) return true; else return false;
}
```

Will produce this assembly, notice that checkB and checkC are identical (correct brackets means correct precedence and the `!=` operator can stay). While the checkA does give precedence to the equality and then the result is and-ed and that result is used for the return.

```
checkA(int, int):
        mov     eax, 1
        mov     ecx, esi
        sal     eax, cl
        test    eax, eax
        setne   al
        movzx   eax, al
        and     eax, edi
        ret

checkB(int, int):
        mov     ecx, esi
        sar     edi, cl
        mov     eax, edi
        and     eax, 1
        ret

checkC(int, int):
        mov     ecx, esi
        sar     edi, cl
        mov     eax, edi
        and     eax, 1
        ret
```

See the **C** precedence table where the `&` is precedence 2 (right to left) and `!=` is precedence 7 (left to right)

[image: c precedence]

Reference from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

**BUT** if you are using **C++** notice how the precedence table changes, the `&` is 11 and the `!=` is 10:

[image: cpp precedence]

Reference from: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

If I would assume GCC as the toolchain, if you do not provide any dialect then the default will be used:

> The default, if no C language dialect options are given, is
> -std=gnu17.

Or for C++:

> The default, if no C++ language dialect options are given, is
> -std=gnu++17.

GCC reference: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html

Broadly speaking it's better to use more parenthesis than less, instead of depending on the precedence order and making sure you and everybody who reads it understand the caveats of the order, it's considered safer to make the order explicit:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201175/should-i-use-parentheses-in-logical-statements-even-where-not-necessary